# Yet another URL prefix regex question (to be used in C#)

Tags: c#, regex, url

I have seen many regular expressions for Url validation.
In my case I want the Url to be simpler, so the regex should be tighter:

Valid Url **prefixes** look like:

- http[s]://[www.]addressOrIp[.something]/PageName.aspx[?]

This describe a prefix. I will be appending `?x=a&y=b&z=c` later. I just want to check if the web page is live before accessing it, but even before that I want to make sure that it is properly configured. I want to treat `bad url` and `host is down` conditions differently, although when in doubt, I'd rather give a `host is down` message, because that is an ultimate test anyway. Hopefully that makes sense. I guess what I am trying to say - the regex does not need be too aggressive, I just want it to cover say 95% of the cases.

This is C# - centric, so Perl regex extensions are not helpful to me; let's stick to the lowest common denominator.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `Uri` class:

```
Uri uri;

if (!Uri.TryCreate(str, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
    //Bad bad bad!!!
if (uri.Scheme != "http" && uri.Scheme != "https")
    //Bad bad bad!!!
if (uri.Host.IndexOf('.') <0)
    //Bad bad bad!!!
```

Comment: Cool! I suppose I can also do `IndexOf(".aspx")`. Was that the purpose of looking for a dot? For instance: `http://www.somehost.com/MyPage.aspx?a=b` contains two dots in it. In this very example, which part will `uri.Host` cover?

Comment: `Uri.Host` will be `www.somehost.com`.  The `IndexOf` call forces a TLD.  You can add whatever checks you want; see the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Use [System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) instead.

Then you will be able to work with your URL parts such as [Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx), [Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.scheme.aspx), [PathAndQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.pathandquery.aspx) etc and check the necessary conditions.